# ¿Comó hago para reajustar el tamaño del fondo de mi pagina web?

Tags: php, html

estaba desarrollando mi pagina web y durante algunas modificaciones note que hay un espacio en blanco a la izquie[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]rda de la pagina.

Comment: Usa el inspector de propiedades de chrome hasta que descubras el elemento que está provocando este desplazamiento. Puedes hacer un clic derecho con el ratón situando el puntero sobre cualquier elemento de la página para ver su HTML y los estilos que se están aplicando. Seguramente tienes algun ancho, margen o padding que te esta provocando el problema, es dificil precisar más sin poder acceder a tu página / código.

Comment: muestra el código para ayudarte

Comment: Hola, por favor añade el código que tienes y los pasos para reproducir el problema. Con una captura de pantalla no podemos ayudarte. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo de estilo debes de configurar el body o el contenedor con

```
Width: 100%
```